# Open a box not new window

Tags: javascript

I have a site with a number of small boxes.  I have used a transition with CSS for each one to enlarge it when hovered over with mouse.

At the moment when you click it opens a new window but I have been asked for it to just open a box which sits over the top of the existing page rather than a new window. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you post the code that is causing the issue? It's hard to determine what is wrong without it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think what you want is a modal dialog. You could use jquery to achieve this. See https://jqueryui.com/dialog/